# Why does the Informix JDBC driver handle unrelated connection strings?

Tags: jdbc, informix

When the Informix JDBC driver is present in my classpath, it seems to intercept and reject all connection strings before the appropriate driver gets the chance.

For example, a completely nonsense connection string like `jdbc:ghmghmghm` will result in the following stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid sub-protocol Invalid sub-protocol: 'ghmghmghm'
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getLocSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:493)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.checkURL(IfxDriver.java:560)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver.connect(IfxDriver.java:208)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
```

My understanding is that well behaved JDBC drivers restrict themselves to connection strings that start with their magic prefix.  Is the Informix driver broken, or do I have unreasonable expectations?

**Update**

If I delete just the Informix driver, but leave all other drivers in place, the exception flips to the much more sane

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ghmghmghm
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
```

Furthermore, there is specific valid connection string `jdbc:sybase:Tds:leeta:5001/leeta_ase1` that will work if the Informix driver is deleted, but will fail (Informix invalid sub-protocol stack trace) if Informix is present.

My conclusion is that Informix is not rejecting completely non-matching connection strings correctly, and that Informix is getting first crack at Sybase connection strings (but not every other connection string type I've tried...)

My Linux JDK is

```
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

but I've seen bad connection strings result in an Infx trace on the official Java 8 on Windows as well.  Have never seen Sybase intercepted on Windows yet, but perhaps that is a classpath ordering issue.

**Update 2**

I can't repro my claim that completely valid connection strings were being intercepted and rejected by Informix.  I must have been trying subtly bad strings, seeing the Informix stack, deleting the Informix driver in response, then considering the stack from the correct driver to be a win (as it allowed quick repair of the connection string).

I see a few ways to improve things:

- Stop using `DriverManager` whenever the driver class is known (instantiate the driver directly and call `getConnection()` on it)
- Write a replacement for `DriverManager.getConnection()` that at least reports all the rejection stacks via `Throwable.addSuppressed()`
- Monkey with the Java classpath to try to make Informix (and other bad actors) show up later in the driver list (per [@jonathan-leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818279/why-does-the-informix-jdbc-driver-handle-unrelated-connection-strings?noredirect=1#comment57387784_34818279))
- Use `DriverManager.(de)registerDriver()` to move bad actors (either a static list or dynamically tested at runtime) to the end of the driver list

Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: what other JDBC drivers are on your class path?  Have you tried printing the contents of the `jdbc.drivers` system prop?

Comment: Can you afford to ensure that the Informix driver is last on your list?  Can you ensure that it is last?  Would that be a sufficient workaround pro tem?

Comment: You have also tested this with real connection strings? Because a potential cause of `jdbc:ghmghmghm` failing could be a parsing problem, as JDBC specifies that the url should be `jdbc:<subprotocol>:<driver specific part>`, and `jdbc:ghmghmghm` fails that requirement ;)

Comment: Hard to see why you're asking here, instead of asking the vendor.

Comment: I'm pretty certain some versions, at least, of the Informix driver is buggy in this respect. I've had problems with the Informix driver intercepting valid Netezza connection URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in the Informix driver (but a minor one at best). A well-behaved JDBC driver is required to follow the expectations defined in [`java.sql.Driver.connect(String url, Properties properties)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-) (emphasis mine):

> Attempts to make a database connection to the given URL. The driver
>   **should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kind of driver to
>   connect** to the given URL. This will be common, as when the JDBC driver
>   manager is asked to connect to a given URL it passes the URL to each
>   loaded driver in turn.
>
> The driver **should throw an SQLException if it is the right driver to
>   connect** to the given URL but has trouble connecting to the database.

The `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection` will query the `connect` method of all registered drivers one by one. If the driver returns `null` it will continue with the next driver. If a driver returns a connection, that connection is returned to the caller. If all drivers return `null`, then an `SQLException` is thrown with the *"No suitable driver found for [url]"* message.

If a driver throws `SQLException`, the last thrown exception is kept, and driver manager will continue with the next driver. If all other drivers reject the connection attempt with `null`, then the last exception will be thrown instead of the *"No suitable driver..."* exception. As far as I know in older Java versions it would actual stop trying other drivers. But the code of `DriverManager` (at least since Oracle/Sun Java 5) protects against this, and prevents misbehaving drivers from monopolizing JDBC, and allows multiple drivers for the same database (and protocol) to be tried.

So, unless your Java version has a different `DriverManager` implementation (one that stops at the first exception), it should continue with the other registered drivers and if any of them accept the URL then there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed in the latest Informix JDBC Driver Version (JDBC.4.10.JC8DE).

Comment: Sadly the new driver also breaks LOB support, but I guess you can't have everything.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `DriverManager` doc:

> As part of its initialization, the DriverManager class will attempt to load the driver classes referenced in the "jdbc.drivers" system property. This allows a user to customize the JDBC Drivers used by their applications. For example in your ~/.hotjava/properties file you might specify:
>
> `jdbc.drivers=foo.bah.Driver:wombat.sql.Driver:bad.taste.ourDriver`

So, say you have 3 JDBC Drivers, such that your `jdbc.drivers` property looks like this:

```
jdbc.drivers=com.DriverA:com.DriverB:com.DriverC
```

If you call `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:driverA:blahblah");` the DriverManager doesn't know which driver in the `jdbc.drivers` property to use, so it has to iterate over all of them.

**DriverManager.getConnection() probably does something similar to this:**

```java
public Connection getConnection(String url) {

    Set<Driver> drivers = // drivers in 'jdbc.drivers' prop

    SQLException failure = null;

    for(Driver driver : drivers) {
        try {
            Connection conn = driver.connect(url);
            if(conn != null)
                return conn;
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            // potentially not trying to connect to the right driver
            if(failure == null)
                failure = sqle;
        }
    }

    // If we get here, no drivers could connect
    if(failure != null)
        throw failure;
    else // no connection obtained, but no drivers complained
        throw new SQLException("No driver found for URL " + url);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
(Code sample has been updated)

It appears that OpenJDK tolerates the scenario where a Driver returns null for a protocol that it doesn't recognize, and it also tolerates the scenario where a Driver throws an Exception for a protocol that it doesn't recognize.

I'd argue that OpenJDK should never throw an exception that came directly from a Driver, and always throw a new SQLException if no driver was found for the URL.

Comment: So if I understand you, any connection string that fails in the *appropriate* driver might result in a stack from an unrelated driver, because it was the last one tried?

Comment: Potentially. I'm sure a robust JDK would handle this in a smart way.  It looks like OpenJDK 6 for example throws the first failure it sees (assuming all attempts to connect fail)

Comment: I've done some testing of this theory and updated my question; I think my findings support the possibility that Informix has a problem.

Comment: interesting findings, I've updated answer too.  I'd also recommend taking a look at the OpenJDK source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/sql/DriverManager.java#DriverManager.getConnection%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Properties%2Cjava.lang.Class%29

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, if a driver doesn't support a protocol, it should return `null` to reject the attempt, if the driver does support the protocol (but it has syntax errors, invalid properties, etc, then it should throw an `SQLException`. If `DriverManager` receive an `SQLException` it will forward that exception, if it receives `null` it continue with the next driver.

Comment: After looking at the driver manager code more closely, it looks like it does continue with other drivers after the `SQLException` is thrown, as far as I know it didn't do that in the past.